# How to enable Gzip compression on dynamic content using Jetty 9

Tags: solr, jetty, gzip

I'm running SolR using Jetty 9. It works fine.

I have the following configuration: 1 web server (IIS), 1 solr Server (Jetty).

To optimize bandwith usage, I want to enable GZIP compression between those 2 servers.

I tried to add this into `jetty/etc/webdefault.xml` :

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
      <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,application/json,image/svg+xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I get the following error :

```
2013-06-19 11:16:19.534:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED GzipFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1312)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.updateBeans(ContainerLifeCycle.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setHandlers(HandlerCollection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.setHandlers(ContextHandlerCollection.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.addHandler(HandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
2013-06-19 11:16:19.534:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3dada196{/,file:/E:/Solr/jetty-9/webapps/ROOT/,STARTING}{E:\Solr\jetty-9\webapps\ROOT}
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:743)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1312)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.updateBeans(ContainerLifeCycle.java:713)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setHandlers(HandlerCollection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.setHandlers(ContextHandlerCollection.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.addHandler(HandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1233)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 8):

Normally, you add GzipFilter to your webapp's `WEB-INF/web.xml` and include the `jetty-servlets.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

However, it might be possible to have it configured at the top level jetty server level.

For starters, the error you are getting indicates that the jetty-servlets.jar is not present on your server classpath.

To test this, run the following from your jetty-distribution standalone.

```
$ java -jar start.jar --version

Active Options: [Server, annotations, client, ext, jaas, jmx, jndi, jndi.demo, jsp, plus, resources, rewrite, websocket]
Version Information on 36 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the OPTIONS=[option,option,...] command line option will be reflected here.
 0:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 1:  3.0.0.v201112011016 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar
 2:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 3:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-continuation-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 4:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 5:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 6:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 7:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 8:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 9:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-annotations-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
10:  1.1.0.v201108011116 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-1.1.0.v201108011116.jar
11:  3.1.0.v200803061910 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.v200803061910.jar
12:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-client-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
13:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jaas-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
14:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jmx-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
15:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jndi-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
16:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-plus-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
17:  1.1.0.v201105071233 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar
18:  1.4.1.v201005082020 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar
19:                1.1.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar
20:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi.demo/test-mock-resources-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
21:  2.2.0.v201303151357 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/com.sun.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
22:  2.2.0.v201303151357 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
23:  1.2.0.v201105211821 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar
24:  2.2.0.v201112011158 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar
25:  2.2.2.v201112011158 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar
26:  1.2.0.v201112081803 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar
27: 3.8.2.v20130121-145325 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
28:                (dir) | ${jetty.home}/resources
29:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-rewrite-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
30:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-api-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
31:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-common-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
32:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
33:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
34:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
35:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
```

This will show you the server classpath, as you can see, the standard distribution has no `jetty-servlets.jar` available by default.  However the `start.config` included in the  `start.jar` has a predefined `OPTION` for `servlets`

Note: To see the list of `OPTIONS` that are available to you run

```
$ java -jar start.jar --list-options
```

Note: To see the `start.config` that the `start.jar` is using.

```
$ java -jar start.jar --list-config
```

Finally, to use this information, we can simply make the `servlets` `OPTION` available on every startup of jetty by editing the `start.ini`.

```
$ echo "OPTIONS=servlets" >> start.ini 

$ java -jar start.jar --version
Active Options: [Server, annotations, client, ext, jaas, jmx, jndi, jndi.demo, jsp, plus, resources, rewrite, servlets, websocket]
Version Information on 37 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the OPTIONS=[option,option,...] command line option will be reflected here.
 0:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 1:  3.0.0.v201112011016 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.0.jar
 2:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 3:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-continuation-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 4:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 5:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 6:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 7:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 8:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
 9:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-annotations-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
10:  1.1.0.v201108011116 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-1.1.0.v201108011116.jar
11:  3.1.0.v200803061910 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/org.objectweb.asm-3.1.0.v200803061910.jar
12:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-client-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
13:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jaas-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
14:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jmx-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
15:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jndi-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
16:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-plus-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
17:  1.1.0.v201105071233 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.activation-1.1.0.v201105071233.jar
18:  1.4.1.v201005082020 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar
19:                1.1.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.transaction-1.1.1.v201105210645.jar
20:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi.demo/test-mock-resources-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
21:  2.2.0.v201303151357 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/com.sun.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
22:  2.2.0.v201303151357 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.el-2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
23:  1.2.0.v201105211821 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar
24:  2.2.0.v201112011158 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar
25:  2.2.2.v201112011158 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar
26:  1.2.0.v201112081803 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar
27: 3.8.2.v20130121-145325 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jsp/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
28:                (dir) | ${jetty.home}/resources
29:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-rewrite-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
30:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlets-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
31:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-api-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
32:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-common-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
33:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-server-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
34:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-servlet-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
35:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
36:      9.0.3.v20130506 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-9.0.3.v20130506.jar
```

At this point you can see that `jetty-servlets.jar` is now available at the server side. (entry #30 in my output above)

Comment: Hi. 
Thank you for your answer, very detailled. Know, I understand how it work.

jetty-servlets.jar is now successfully loaded and there are no exceptions. 

But I have still a problem : I try to request SolR (POST request, with Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate) but response are not gzipped. I try to add application/xml into the webdefault.xml, but it didn't work (I use Fiddler).

Have you any idea of how to debug it ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @heisenberg I'm having the same issue - did this work for you eventually? GZIP does not work for me even for GET requests. I have set the filter in override-web.xml.

Comment: @IceMan just adding it to override-web.xml isn't enough for jetty or your webapp to use it.  Your context deployable should also reference the override-web.xml as its override.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Yes, I have defined the following   <Set name="overrideDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/cc.d/override-web.xml</Set> 
This override-web.xml has the gzip filter defined. I'm using the latest Jetty 9

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the answer why the post requests were not compressed; only GET requests are compressed by the filter by default. Add

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

To compress POSTs.